# How do I start a http server and then open a web browser?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I´m trying this:

```
import multiprocessing
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import webbrowser
import time

def application(environ, start_response):   
    start_response("200 OK", [("Content-Type", "text/plain")])
    return ["Hello!"]


class Server(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run(self):
        print "HTTP Server starts."
        server = make_server(host = "127.0.0.1", 
                             port = 88, 
                             app = application)
        try:
            server.serve_forever()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            print "HTTP Server stopped."
        raise

httpd = Server()
httpd.start()
#webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:88")
time.sleep(3)
httpd.terminate()
httpd.join()
print "End"
```

If I uncomment the webbrowser line, the browser won't stop opening new windows. Why?

I still don't really understand the multiprocessing module, but something like this should be simple. How is this done?

**edit:**

The first note at http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html "requires that the **main** module be importable by the children", so:

```
    if __name__=='__main__':            
        httpd = Server()
        httpd.start()
        webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:88")
        time.sleep(3)
        httpd.terminate()
        httpd.join()
        print "End"
```

Seems to works fine.

But I wonder how do I signal SystemExit to the Server. Better ways?

Comment: How are you starting this program? i.e. "python file.py"?

Comment: I'm testing with IDLE

Comment: I'll test now, but it looks like it would work just fine (and as expected)

Comment: Yep, works fine for me on OSX from command line.

Comment: Are you by chance running on windows?

Comment: Yep. Win7-64, python2.7-32. Just tested from cmd and had a different result, lots of "End", then CTRL+C and lots of "HTTP Server stopped" and tracebacks.

Comment: Oh! just tested with "if __name__=='__main__'" and works from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows cannot fork the existing process to create a child process, like it is possible on Unices. There are a few extra things to consider on windows: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing#windows

So in windows a new process is created and the code imported. Any code that runs unconditionally will be executed in the child process. In your case creating a new server process and a browser window. Which will import your main module...

The solution is to use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom, as you discovered.